# aws cloudfront - Access Denied with S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I've create a cloudfront distribution and S3 bucket.
I'm encountering `Access Denied` error when accessing Cloudfront url
`asdf123456.cloudfront.net`

I tried to add `custom error message` in my cloudformation template but still not working.

My Json Template in Cloudformation

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",

    "Parameters": {
        "S3BucketName": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "test-server-dev"
        },
        "S3BucketWebName": {
          "Type": "String",
          "Default": "test-web-dev"
        },
        "CloudfrontDistributionOriginId": {
          "Type": "String",
          "Default": "test_dev"
        }
    },

    "Resources": {
      "S3BucketWeb": {
        "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "Properties": {
          "BucketName": {
              "Ref": "S3BucketWebName"
           }
        }
      },
      "CloudfrontDistributionWeb": {
        "Type" : "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
        "Properties" : {
            "DistributionConfig" : {
              "CustomErrorResponses" : [
                {
                  "ErrorCachingMinTTL" : 300,
                  "ErrorCode" : 403,
                  "ResponseCode" : 200,
                  "ResponsePagePath" : "/index.html"
                }
              ],
              "DefaultCacheBehavior": {            
                  "AllowedMethods" : ["GET", "HEAD"],
                  "CachedMethods" : ["GET", "HEAD"],
                  "CachePolicyId" : "658327ea-f89d-4fab-a63d-7e88639e58f6",
                  "Compress" : false,
                  "TargetOriginId" : {
                    "Ref": "S3BucketWebName"
                  },
                  "ViewerProtocolPolicy" : "redirect-to-https"
              },
              "DefaultRootObject" : "index.html",
              "Enabled" : true,
              "HttpVersion": "http2",
              "IPV6Enabled" : true,
              "Origins" : [
                {
                  "ConnectionAttempts" : 3,
                  "ConnectionTimeout" : 10,
                  "DomainName" : {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                      "S3BucketWeb",
                      "DomainName"
                    ]
                  },
                  "Id" : {
                    "Ref": "S3BucketWebName"
                  },
                  "S3OriginConfig": {
                    "OriginAccessIdentity" : ""
                  }
                }
              ],
              "Restrictions" : {
                "GeoRestriction" : {
                  "RestrictionType" : "none"
                }
              },
              "ViewerCertificate" : {
                "CloudFrontDefaultCertificate" : true
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Update

Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EBJE9SUE3W57Q"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-web-dev/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you setup bucket policy?

Comment: @Marcin I updated bucket policy above

Comment: Why your `OriginAccessIdentity` is empty?

Comment: @Marcin because I want to create new OriginAccessIdentity automatically for testing, so I manually create the `OriginAccessIdentity` in Aws Console.

Comment: But is it associated with your CF distro? Is it the same one as in your bucket policy?

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand the question properly but if you are getting s3 access denied while uploading your cloud formation template then you might be missing a security group or IAM role which are allowed to perform such actions and then attach it to the formation template itself.

Comment: sure thanks may be the object you are trying to access in the S3 itself has restrictions attached to it or maybe the bucket policies are restricting access.